# problem with adding an image on a JFrame with a label

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

so I have an image in the folder of my project and I want to upload it on a label in a JFrame so the image will be show in the user interface, but when I run the project I only get the grey screen the picture is not being showed. this is the entire code, thank you eberyone.

```
//Main part of Java Eat//
package programming.javaeat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class JavaEat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int ancho = 700;
    int largo = 600;
    frame.setSize(ancho,largo);
    
    //Creación del label//
   
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    
    // imágen en el label//
    ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("fondo.jpg");
        label.setIcon(imagen);
        
    //agregar el label al frame//
     frame.add(label);  
     
     //Mostrar el frame junto con el label//
      frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
    
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, using the design and the palette from the JFrame, coding it in another way...

Comment: Don't put images in the src folder.  [Location-Independent Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)